# Seperate single lambda invokation logs into several logStreams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-nodejs

Im using nodeJS over aws-lambda to run a system test.

Im testing several components and want the **whole test be part of a single lambda function** (development scale considerations ).

Nevertheless , to quickly detect the failures and what xaused them , I want the test of each component to write to a seperate logStream ( under the same log group )

For example . If  Testing Lambda is testing 3  components CompA, CompB , CompC.
I would like it to write into three diffrent logStreams on each run .

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the best solution for this is to separate your invocation into 4 lambas:

1. LambdaOrchestrator
2. LambdaCompA
3. LambdaCompB
4. LambdaCompC

Your first lambda will orchestrate the other runs and at the end you will have 4 separate logs.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Nevertheless, I explicitly stated I don't want to break into several lamdas ('whole test be part of a single lambda function')